# Arithmetic operations in donald knuth's Mix assembly language 1.3.1

Tags: assembly, knuth

I have been reading Donald Knuth's The Art of Programming, Volume 1, in which MIX is used as the assembly language. In the section where Knuth talks about arithmetic operations in MIX, I didn't understand how the subtraction, multiplication and division operations are carried out.

For example, the text book has this:

register A has the following word code: `-| 1235 | 0 | 3 | 1` and a memory cell, say M, has the following word code: `-| 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0`.

The book says on performing DIV 100 the result is: `rA(+ | 0 | 617 | ? | ?)`, `rX(- | 0 | 0 | 0 | ? | 1)` .
Can anyone help me with this?

As I know, should it be `rA(+ | 0 | 617 | 5 | 1)`, `rX(- | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1)`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have enough setup information here for the given DIV instruction, plus you're mixing 4-part word form and the 5-part word form, but let's focus on dividing:

- dividend = -1235000301
- divisor = -200
- -1235000301 / -200 = 6175001.505
- quotient = 6175001
- remainder = -101 = 0.505 * -200

| Component | MIX 4-part Decimal | MIX 5-part Decimal | Numeric Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dividend | `- | 1235 | 00 | 03 | 01` | `- | 12 | 35 | 00 | 03 | 01` | -1,235,000,301 |
| divisor | `- | 0000 | 00 | 02 | 00` | `- | 00 | 00 | 00 | 02 | 00` | -200 |
| quotient | `+ | 0006 | 17 | 50 | 01` | `+ | 00 | 06 | 17 | 50 | 01` | 6,175,001 |
| remainder | `- | 0000 | 00 | 01 | 01` | `- | 00 | 00 | 00 | 01 | 01` | -101 |

In a shorter version of the above word forms, strip leading zeros — e.g. 1 means 01 — but don't forget to include leading zeros to obtain the full and proper numeric value.

Comment: Hi.

Sory but it seems to me that your answer not completly full.

There are 2 appropriate variants for bytes. 6-bits of 1/0 (binary) or 2 bits of 0-9 (decimal).

Your answer for decimal system. But for binary system answer will be |617|32|1| and reminder |1|1|

That's why 4-th byte of quotient with mark ?. But actually I don't undestand why 5-th byte of quatient and 4-th byte of reminder are "?" in the book. Because |617|50|1| / |1|1| (decimal) and |617|32|1| / |1|1| (binary) differs only by 4-th byte of quotient.

Comment: Actually I calculates so:

1. Decimal bytes

(1235 * 100^3 + 03 * 100 + 1) / 2 * 100 = 1235000301 / 200
Q: 6175001 (617 * 100 ^2 + 50 * 100 + 1)   R:101 (1 * 100 + 1)


2. Binary bytes

(1235 * 64^3 + 3 * 64 + 1) / 2 * 64 = 323748033/ 128
Q: 2529281 (617 * 64 ^2 + 32 * 64 + 1)   R:65 (1 * 64 + 1)

If you would split 2 and 3 byte (617) for these answers you see that for decimal system bytes are |6|17| and for binary system bytes are |9|41|

Comment: @D.Tyagniy, I take this as a problem with partial answer given in the book.  As such, 2,529,281 doesn't fit the partial answer whereas 6,175,001 does.  Therefore, I deduced that the problem was given in decimal form and answer expected in decimal form.  I believe that you are correct about the binary output when taking this as given in binary input.  But the partial answer in the book fits only the decimal form.

Comment: Ok. I see. Thank you for your answer. But then can you explain me why there are 3 question marks “?” in the book in this example. How author calculates it? Thank you.